# Infinite loop in class

Tags: python, pygame

I keep getting an infinite loop in this class and this time it's definitely coming from `.ExNote()` but I have no idea why. I've simplified it down so here you go:

```
class Note():
    x=[0]
    y=[0]
    def __init__(self, Num, staff, note, notetype):
        self.staff = staff
        self.note = note
        self.notetype = notetype
        self.Num=Num
    def ExNote(self):                    
        screen.blit(self.notetype, (self.x[self.Num], self.y[self.Num]))
        print('exnote')
going = True
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    Note(0, '0R', '40', EthnoteIMG).ExNote()
```

returrns

```
exnote
exnote
exnote.....
```

Why doesn't it stop after doing the function once?

Comment: ...seriously? `while going:` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Because you never do anything except tell it to loop. Read the code. `while going:` - Where do you see anything that changes `going` to make it stop looping? And if you only want it to call the function once, why are you using a loop at all? Loops are for **repeating things**.

Comment: Ohhhh so it loops through the class function in order to blit the image over and over I didn't realize that's how it works. I don't know how in the heck I got this to work the first time

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please insert a break function at the end of your code

while True:
          Bla blabla
          Blablabla
             break

That should kill it

Comment: If you put in a break after a single call, there's no reason to have a loop at all, is there?

Comment: No need for a loop... An if statement would do but since he has a loop already... He should use break then.

Comment: Um... No. The loop should be removed, because a loop is for **repeating**. If you don't want anything to repeat, remove the loop.

Answer (score 1):

"while going:" is a loop.  It needs to be set to False inside the loop to stop it.  With just the code you've shown, the while loop isn't needed and could be removed altogether.  You said you're only showing a portion of the code, so I'll leave it up to you to decide when the loop should stop.

```
class Note():
    x=[0]
    y=[0]
    def __init__(self, Num, staff, note, notetype):
        self.staff = staff
        self.note = note
        self.notetype = notetype
        self.Num=Num
    def ExNote(self):                    
        screen.blit(self.notetype, (self.x[self.Num], self.y[self.Num]))
        print('exnote')
going = True
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    Note(0, '0R', '40', EthnoteIMG).ExNote()
    if <your stop condition>:
       going = False # You need to set going to False inside your loop to get it to stop

    OR

    going = <some function that returns false when appropriate>
```